# How do I download multiple files using one HTTP 1.1 request

Tags: linux, http, terminal, network-programming, netcat

Using nc, I was able to download one file with:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: {insert host name}
```

But I can't figure out how to download multiple files in one request

Comment: HTTP was design to "get" one "file" per request. What is the problem you need to solve? Why do you need to get multiple files with a single request?

Comment: you could fetch multiple files through single tcp connection (just feed them all into netcat) but there will be multiple http requests with corresponding responses in this connection and manual parsing of such response could be nightmarish. You can use wget instead of netcat to do it just specify multiple URLs in the same command line : ```wget URL1 URL2```